# Laravel why store array position instead his name

Tags: laravel

why store array position instead his name.

**BLADE**

My blade file where i have my list of category

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="role">Category</label>
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <div class="select">
                        {!! Form::select('category', $categorylist,null,array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**controller**

my controller where take data from query to send to blade file

```
$categorylist = Category::where('category','=','cat')
                    ->groupby('catlist')
                    ->pluck('catlist');

                    //dd($categorylist);


return view('addcategory')
    ->with(
        [
            'categorylist' => $categorylist
        ]
);
```

Comment: What your question really is? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Read the [docs on dropdown lists](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#drop-down-lists) they expect an array with keys and values and the key is what is passed to the server. The value is just for display

Comment: @apokryfos thx i'll read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the full name instead of array ID, try this in your controller

```
$categorylist = Category::where('category','=','cat')
    ->groupby('catlist')
    ->pluck('catlist')
    ->keyBy(function ($name) { return $name; });
```